# Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence such that all non-trivial (*) subsequence converges, does $(a_n)$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence such that all non-trivial subsequence converges.

A subsequence $(a_{\phi(n)})$ is trivial if $\exists N,\exists \alpha, \forall n ≥ N, $ $\phi(n) = n + \alpha$.

Does  $(a_n)$ converge ?

I deliberately put aside what would make the statement trivial.

**That was solved by ThePortakal.**

---

Now, if I complete the definition of a trivial subsequence by :

A subsequence $(a_{\phi(n)})$ is also trivial if $\exists N,\exists \alpha, \beta, \forall n ≥ N, $ $\phi(n) = \alpha n + \beta$.

Is the statement true ?

EDIT : It seems uninteresting since we just have to entwine subsequences of that type.

Comment: Consider $(b_n) = (a_1,a_2,a_5,a_6,a_9,a_{10}, \dots)$ and $(c_n)=(a_3,a_4,a_7,a_8,a_{11},a_{12}, \dots)$. These are nontrivial subsequences with limits $L_1$ and $L_2$. Now pick a nontrivial $d_n$ getting values from $b_n$ and $c_n$ infinitely many times. For example, $(d_n)=(a_1,a_3,a_5,a_8,a_9,a_{12},\dots)$. Consider the subsequences of $d_n$.

Comment: Yes, I was speaking about these entwined subsequences. We can always go back to something like the trivial case like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{2n} = L_1$ (the limit of the subsequence of even terms)

and let $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{2n+1} = L_2$ (the limit of the subsequence of odd terms)

Now consider the sequence $a_{3n}$. Let $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{3n}=L_3$.

Then all subsequences of $a_{3n}$ converges to $L_3$.

Now, $a_{6n}$ is a subsequence of both $a_{3n}$ and $a_{2n}$, so, $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{6n} = L_3 = L_1$ must hold.

Also, $a_{6n+3}$ is a subsequence of both $a_{3n}$ and $a_{2n+1}$, so, $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{6n+3} = L_3 = L_2$.

These imply that $L_1=L_2$ and therefore all terms (both even and odd ones) converge to the same limit.

Answer (score 0):

If $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy-sequence, then since at least one subsequence converges, $(a_n)$ converges.

If  $(a_n)$ is not a Cauchy-sequence then : $\exists \epsilon, \forall N, \exists n,m ≥ N $, $|a_n - a_m| ≥ \epsilon.$ Using this, we could make a non-trivial subsequence (by imposing $|\phi(n+2) - \phi(n+1)|> |\phi(n+1) - \phi(n)|$ for all $n$) which cannot converges.

Comment: If $(a_n)$ is not a Cauchy sequence, then $\exists \epsilon, \forall N, \exists m,n \geq N: |a_m-a_n| \geq \epsilon$. The construction of a non-convergent sub-sequence seems more or less true to me, but I'm in doubt.

Comment: Yes, on the moment I thought it was equivalent, but it is not.